# how to add/remove a class or style with jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following code which shows nested ul and hides the other open ones on click.  my question is how can i add a background image to the parent li a that opens the nested ul and removes the background image from the parent li a of the ones it closes?

here is my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul ul').hide();

    $('ul li > a').click(function(event) {
        $('ul ul').hide('slow');
        $(this).parent().find('ul').show('slow');
    });

});;
```

Comment: to add a style or class in jquery use addClass/removeClass or css

Comment: jQuery has methods called .addClass() and .removeClass() all you have to do it call .addClass('classNameHereWithTheQuotes')

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
// will add the class
$('#item').addClass('myClass');

// will remove the class
$('#item').removeClass('myClass'); 

// will toggle the class (add it if doesn't have it or remove it if it does)
$('#item').toggleClass('myClass');
```

and inline styles;

```
// will override those properties
$('#item').css({'color':'red','background':'blue'});
```

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding correctly, you could grab the parent `li` with the parent function, then set a background image with the css function

```
$('ul li > a').click(function(event) {
    $(this).parent("li").css("background-image", "url('foo.png')");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add or remove classes using [addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) or [removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).